# Extract all numbers (int and floats) after specific word

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

Assuming I have the following string:

```
str = """
         HELLO 1 Stop #$**& 5.02‼️ 16.1 
         regex

         5 ,#2.3222
      """
```

I want to export all numbers , Whether int or float after the word "stop" with no case sensitive . so the expected results will be :

```
[5.02, 16.1, 5, 2.3222]
```

The farthest I have come so far is by using PyPi regex from other post here:

```
regex.compile(r'(?<=stop.*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?', regex.I)
```

but this expression gives me only [5.02, 16.1]

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Do you have a _specific_ question?

Comment: Yes , question updated

Answer (score 5):

Yet another one, albeit with the newer `regex` module:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|Stop)\D+\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/3YsyIq/1/).

---

In `Python`, this could be

```
import regex as re

string = """
         HELLO 1 Stop #$**& 5.02‼️ 16.1 
         regex

         5 ,#2.3222
      """

pattern = re.compile(r'(?:\G(?!\A)|Stop)\D+\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?')

numbers = pattern.findall(string)
print(numbers)
```

And would yield

```
['5.02', '16.1', '5', '2.3222']
```

Don't name your variables after inbuilt-functions, like `str`, `list`, `dict` and the like.

---

If you need to go further and limit your search within some bounds (e.g. all numbers between `Stop` and `end`), you could as well use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|Stop)(?:(?!end)\D)+\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?
#           ^^^        ^^^
```

See another [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/PVLKaP/1/).

Comment: Nice one, Jan. `^.*\bStop\b(\D*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|\G(?1)` seems to also work with PCRE2 ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sALreI/1)), where `(?1)` is a subroutine that reuses the code in capture group 1), but I can't get it to work [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21QiGxGMjg4uIqLilSsFVQUlLiUoABD1cfH38FQ4XgkvwCBWUVLS01BVM9A6NHDXve7@hXMDTTM1RAKAabxoXgmyroKBvpGRsZGUHFQEZzFaVXAG0pUo/T04pJApkbk6QR46IV4x2Toq1hbxWjB6Q17TVrYtw17A011bm4Cooy80o0ilL10jLzUhJzcjSAJugoAB2rqcn1/z8A), but...

Comment: ...your regex works fine [there](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21QiGxGMjg4uIqLilSsFVQUlLiUoABD1cfH38FQ4XgkvwCBWUVLS01BVM9A6NHDXve7@hXMDTTM1RAKAabxoXgmyroKBvpGRsZGUHFQEZzFaVXAG0pUtewt4px17BXjHHUrAEZrxnjoh3jHZOiDZLQA9Ka9upcXAVFmXklGkWpemmZeSmJOTkaQO06CkCXampy/f8PAA). Do you see a problem with my variant?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: It does not really work, see [**here**](https://tio.run/##RY4xqsJAEIb7OcUQRXejLGZFi4CkURSeYGHpKihG3SKbZbNFAq94N/A6r/A0XsAjxDEoTjPz//x8/9jKX3IzrGud2dx5dOk5LXFf0AEAhXc4wSAIAD@zmC2XK4xw7XOLrXYYdnAkBvL@d3v8XzEaiwi/4YYGXz3CfkuKoZTy7b3Q4M4ltbjuToTq8OKqA1PTUP2oY48lsRK0ecJ/1ZwlEe8CnHKHGWpDfHHS5qh96hhR@kgP87hhk6iImonC7g3jjWedNp5RZlPG1ZZDXT8B) (you have two many matches, see the `"1"`). You can get it to work with the matched objects. Capture groups matched inside of recursion are not accessible, see the [documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre). Did that help?

Comment: Yes, helpful, but I still don't understand why it works with [PCRE2](https://regex101.com/r/WKJEkc/1/) but not at Tio.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Here is [the correct demo of your solution](https://tio.run/##LY1NCsIwFIT37xSPVmxSJdhIXQjSjaKg4MKlUVD6YxY2IY1QwYU38DouPI0X8Ag1FmczM4v5Rl/tSZXDppFnrYxFkxVZjYfKBQCocIKe5y1mq9UaI9xYpdHvhGEXYzbg7/vr83xgNGIRArZq5/AvMfZ9zoacc8cAMEXtcCbYs1AcfyhxJGIaiqVIeyQZC@acJvQm5iSJaACgjSwt2dasMOqiCcVcGaxRlu6G5bJMpc0Mcdg@VnRHoWm@). You might want to use `rgx = r'(?ms)^.*?\bStop\b(\D*\K\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|\G(?1)'` here, probably, with `[x.group() for x in re.finditer(rgx, s)]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It seems all captures are lost when you recurse the pattern with a subroutine and use `regex.findall`. With `regex.finditer` and your regex in the Python code at tio, you get the whole matches, but even numbers before `Stop` are extracted, because of `\G(?1)`, as `\G` also matches the start of a string, and your string in Python code starts with a line break, and the `.*` does not match across lines as you did not use the `re.DOTALL` flag. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sALreI/2) showing how it is matched.

Answer (score 3):

You get only the first 2 numbers, as `.*` does not match a newline.

You can add update the flags to `regex.I | regex.S` to have the dot match a newline.

```
import regex

text = """
         HELLO 1 Stop #$**& 5.02‼️ 16.1 
         regex

         5 ,#2.3222
      """

pattern = regex.compile(r'(?<=\bstop\b.*)\d+(?:\.\d+)?', regex.I | regex.S)

print(regex.findall(pattern, text))
```

Output

```
['5.02', '16.1', '5', '2.3222']
```

See a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21gourJLWiRMFWQUlJiUsBBjxcfXz8FQwVgkvyCxSUVbS01BRM9QyMHjXseb@jX8HQTM9QAaEYag6cb6qgo2ykZ2xkZAQVAxnNVZBYUpJalAe0CaxeLzk/tyAzJ1WjSF3D3sY2JqkYaFVMkp6WZkyKtoa9VYwekNa0V9eBKvdUqIGygjWBhhVl5pVoQPhpmXkpiTk5GlALdBRAHtLU/P8fAA)

---

If you want to print the numbers **after** the word "stop", you can also use python `re` and match stop, and then capture in a group all that follows.

Then you can take that group 1 value, and find all the numbers.

```
import re
 
text = """
         HELLO 1 Stop #$**& 5.02‼️ 16.1 
         regex
 
         5 ,#2.3222
      """
pattern = r"\bStop\b(.+)"
 
m = re.search(pattern, text, re.S|re.I)
 
if m:
    print(re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)*", m.group(1)))
```

Output

```
['5.02', '16.1', '5', '2.3222']
```

Comment: Ha! My now-deleted answer may look familiar.

Comment: @CarySwoveland You can also you the inline modifiers as well :-)

Comment: `\G` might be better suited (+1), variable lookbehinds are expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```py
inp = """
HELLO 1 Stop #$**& 5.02‼️ 16.1 
regex

5 ,#2.3222"""

nums = []
if re.search(r'\bstop\b', inp, flags=re.I):
    inp = re.sub(r'^.*?\bstop\b', '', inp, flags=re.S|re.I)
    nums = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', inp)

print(nums)  # ['5.02', '16.1', '5', '2.3222']
```

The `if` logic above ensures that we only attempt to populate the array of numbers if we are certain that `Stop` appears in the input text.  Otherwise, the default output is just an empty array.  If `Stop` *does* appear, then we strip off that leading portion of the string before using `re.findall` to find all numbers appearing afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

_string = """
          HELLO 1 Stop #$**& 5.02‼️ 16.1
          regex

          5 ,#2.3222
       """

start = _string.find("Stop") + len("Stop")
print(re.findall("[-+]?\d*\.?\d+", _string[start:]))   # ['5.02', '16.1', '5', '2.3222']
```